# linear weights on predictors past values for Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am doing a regression with timeseries using sklearn.linear_model.
I have 20 predictors (X) and 1 target (y).
All the timeseries go from 2016 to today.
I would like to give more importance on recent values and less importance on past values (ideally with linear weights from 2016 ,50% to today, 100%.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Pandas has a built-in exponentially-weighted moving average which gives more weight to recent datapoints. I think you can control the weights used, but you'll need to check how it works in the version of pandas you're using, as the implementation has changed in recent versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sample_weight` when calling its [`fit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) method, which sets individual weights for each sample. You could set it for instance, to a value proportional to the time elapsed since the first date, so that more recent samples have higher weights.